# Postgresql - `serial` column & inheritence (sequence sharing policy)

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

In postgresql, when inherit a `serial` column from parent table, the sequence is shared by parent & child table.

Is it possible to inherit the `serial` column, while let the 2 table have separated sequence values, e.g both table's column could have value `1`.

Is this possible & reasonable, and if yes, how to do that?

---

### @Update

The reasons that I want to avoid sequence sharing are:

- 1. Sharing a single int range by multiple table might use up the
     MAX_INT, using bigint could improve this, but it takes more space
     too.
- 2. There is a kind of resource locking when multiple table doing insert concurrently, so it's a performance issue I guess.
- 3. The id jump from 1 to 5 then might to 1000 don't look as beautiful as it could.

---

### @Summary

**solutions**:

- If want child table have its own sequence, while still keep the global sequence among parent & child table. (*As described in `@wildplasser` 's answer.*)

  Then could add a `sub_id serial` column for each child table.
- If want child table have its own sequence, while don't need a global sequence among parent & child table,

  There there are 2 ways:

  1. Using `int` instead of `serial`. (*As described in `@lsilva` 's answer.*)

     Steps:

     - define type as int or bigint in parent table,
     - for each parent & child table, create a individual sequence,
     - specify default value for int type for each table using nextval of their own sequence,
       don't forget to maintain/reset the sequence, when re-create table,
  2. Define `id serial` directly in child table, and not in parent table.

Comment: Add *another* serial column to the child table?

Comment: @wildplasser You mean there are 2 serial column in child table then? That can work for sure, but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Yes, of course. In most cases it wouldn't make sense, but in this case it could. And there is no better solution (except omit it and use an enumeration like  row_number() over (the parent_sequence) *within* the child table)

Comment: Bear in mind the often misunderstood fact that sequences do not assure a gapless progression of IDs (because of how they interact with transactions and similar races), nor do they enfore uniqueness of the column's values. So adding extra sequences doesn't guarantee you won't happen to get IDs 1,3,5 in table A and 2,4,6 in table B; and keeping the same sequence doesn't stop you manually inserting ID 1 into all the tables. So it might be worth confirming *why* you want to do this, and what properties you expect the separated sequences to have.

Comment: @IMSoP I updated the question to add the reason I want to that.

Comment: `for each parent & child table, create a individual sequence, ... specify default value for int type for each table using nextval of their own sequence, ...` Note: this is exactly the same as my 1st solution (in Postgres, a serial is an int with a sequence *bound* as its default value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP schema tmp CASCADE;
CREATE schema tmp;
set search_path = tmp, pg_catalog;

CREATE TABLE common
        ( seq SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );

CREATE TABLE one
        ( subseq SERIAL NOT NULL
        , payload integer NOT NULL
        )
        INHERITS (tmp.common)
        ;

CREATE TABLE two
        ( subseq SERIAL NOT NULL
        , payload integer NOT NULL
        )
        INHERITS (tmp.common)
        ;

/**
\d common
\d one
\d two
\q
***/

INSERT INTO one(payload)
SELECT gs FROM generate_series(1,5) gs
        ;

INSERT INTO two(payload)
SELECT gs FROM generate_series(101,105) gs
        ;

SELECT * FROM common;
SELECT * FROM one;
SELECT * FROM two;
```

---

Results:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to table tmp.common
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
INSERT 0 5
 seq 
-----
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
  10
(10 rows)

 seq | subseq | payload 
-----+--------+---------
   1 |      1 |       1
   2 |      2 |       2
   3 |      3 |       3
   4 |      4 |       4
   5 |      5 |       5
(5 rows)

 seq | subseq | payload 
-----+--------+---------
   6 |      1 |     101
   7 |      2 |     102
   8 |      3 |     103
   9 |      4 |     104
  10 |      5 |     105
(5 rows)
```

---

But: in fact you don't need the subseq columns, since you can always enumerate them by means of row_number():

```
CREATE VIEW vw_one AS
SELECT seq
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY seq) as subseq
        , payload
FROM one;

CREATE VIEW vw_two AS
SELECT seq
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY seq) as subseq
        , payload
FROM two;
```

[results are identical]

---

And, you could add UNIQUE AND PRIMARY KEY constraints to the child tables, like:

```
CREATE TABLE one
        ( subseq SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE
        , payload integer NOT NULL
        )
        INHERITS (tmp.common)
        ;    
ALTER TABLE one ADD PRIMARY KEY (seq);
```

[similar for table two]

Comment: Ok, this do could be a solution. I will accept it unless another solution better pop up. I am wondering is it possible for postgresql to provide options about sequence sharing when inherit.

Comment: It seems @Isilva 's solution works pretty well too, in the situation where don't need a global id among parent table & all child tables.

Comment: Using window function `row_number()` has some overhead I guess.

Comment: Storing redundant data has some overhead, too.

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

```
Parent table definition:

CREATE TABLE parent_table (
  id bigint NOT NULL,


Child table definition:


CREATE TABLE cild_schema.child_table
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('child_schema.child_table_id_seq'::regclass),
```

I am emulating the serial by using a sequence number as a default.

Comment: You can add a diferent default in the parent table, or use a diferent sequence in another child table

Comment: You mean don't use `serial` type, but use `int` or `bigint` instead, and create a sequence for each parent or child table individually by hand, and specify default value for `int` or `bigint` type for each table using `nextval` of their own sequence ? That seems more simple.

Comment: Note that if you use `CREATE SEQUENCE ... OWNED BY`, an integer column is more-or-less indistinguishable from a `SERIAL` column, which isn't really its own data type anyway.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I mean Eric :) . Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: does not compile. Did you test it?

Comment: I up voted the answer, both the 2 answer could be used in 2 different situation as I summaryed in the updated question, it's hard to say which is better, so I'll just keep it current status, sorry about that. By the way, you need @xxx to get people notified about your comment in your own answer, otherwise other people don't know you have added a comment.

Comment: Can you paste your error @wildplasser ? My application is working this way, so i am sure this will work.

Comment: @lsilva :  `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Parent"
LINE 1: Parent table definition:` `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"` And if I comment that out, and the other line with `:` in it: 
`LINE 4: CREATE TABLE cild_schema.child_table`

Comment: @wildplasser: This was just an example, as you can see is not a complete create table statement, is just the first two lines.

Comment: @Isilva , with your setup, do you do the inserts in the parent table or directly in the child table?